# Как изменить скорость анимации тултипов в angular-material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Как изменить дефолтное значение скорости анимации (animate), которое заложено в библиотеке? Пробовала изменить значение стиля transition в css по селектору - не сработало

```js
TooltipComponent.decorators = [
 { type: Component, args: [{
 selector: 'md-tooltip-component, mat-tooltip-component',
 templateUrl: 'tooltip.html',
 styleUrls: ['tooltip.css'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
 animations: [
   trigger('state', [
     state('void', style({transform: 'scale(0)'})),
     state('initial', style({transform: 'scale(0)'})),
     state('visible', style({transform: 'scale(1)'})),
     state('hidden', style({transform: 'scale(0)'})),
     transition('* => visible', animate('150ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
     transition('* => hidden', animate('150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1)')),
   ])
 ]
```

Comment: к сожалению метаданные никак нельзя оверрайдить, потому что они компилируются в оптимизированный javascript код благодаря компилятору angular, у меня конечно есть идейка, но я не уверен, что она рабочая, отпишусь вам позже

Comment: @overthesanity была бы очень признательна. а вариант с переопределением в css не подойдет?

Comment: нет, эти анимации работают через javascript

Comment: @overthesanity, поняла, но пока нет других идей

Comment: да и кстати зачем вы используете старую версию материала?

Comment: @overthesanity, достался такой проект, мне всего лишь нужно кастомизировать тултипы. если менять версию материала, придется слишком много выкашивать. так что пытаюсь решить проблему с тем, что есть

Comment: я даже не знаю что вам сказать по старой версии, потому что вся документация на данный момент имеет отношение к новой версии, но что я вижу по старым примерам у тултипа есть входные параметры `mdTooltipShowDelay` и `mdTooltipClass`, что дает вам возможность задать собственный класс и попробовать поиграться с анимациями, идите методом проб и ошибок, я тут ничего не могу посоветовать со старым API

Comment: @overthesanity, параметр `mdTooltipShowDelay` отвечает за время с момента наведения на элемент и начало открытия тултипа, если я правильно пониманию. не то, что нужно. мне нужно изменить именно скорость раскрытия тултипа. Пробовала `mdTooltipClass="md-tooltip-options"` в css `.md-tooltip-options { transition: none !important; }` не срабатывает. или я не так делаю?

Comment: а вам сильно горит эта задача? ну то есть анимация тултипа очень важна для бизнеса?) мне кажется вам было бы проще просто забить на это ;))

Comment: @overthesanit,к сожалению, необходимо сделать